# Using chrome.tabs.executeScript to execute an async function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await, es6-promise

I have a function I want to execute in the page using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, running from a browser action popup. The permissions are set up correctly and it works fine with a synchronous callback:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id, 
    { code: `(function() { 
        // Do lots of things
        return true; 
    })()` },
    r => console.log(r[0])); // Logs true
```

The problem is that the function I want to call goes through several callbacks, so I want to use `async` and `await`:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id, 
    { code: `(async function() { 
        // Do lots of things with await
        return true; 
    })()` },
    async r => {
        console.log(r); // Logs array with single value [Object]
        console.log(await r[0]); // Logs empty Object {}
    });
```

The problem is that the callback result `r`. It should be an array of script results, so I expect `r[0]` to be a promise that resolves when the script finishes.

Promise syntax (using `.then()`) doesn't work either.

If I execute the exact same function in the page it returns a promise as expected and can be awaited.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and is there any way around it?

Comment: It would have been interesting if this worked, but I would not have expected it to. The code in the content script and the code in the background context (popup) are running in completely separate processes. I would have been surprised if it worked to `await` a response from an `async` content script. You will need to use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: async/await is just a syntactical sugar that doesn't modify the event loop-based js engine behavior so it won't work.

Comment: In Firefox Web Extensions, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` returns a Promise ,and, according to the MDN documentation, this is compatible with how chrome works too - I haven't found any useful Chrome documentation regarding this though, but it may be something to consider

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync) to convert all of Chrome API's callback functions into promises. Using this `chrome.tabs.executeScript` already returns a promise that resolves when the API callback fires (and rejects if `chrome.runtime.lastError` is populated). That doesn't help me get the result of this script.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah, I was hoping to get a `Promise` or `Symbol.iterator` of promises.

Comment: @Makyen ah, of course! Like exceptions, the value returned is essentially a serialised copy - anything that doesn't make it through `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` is lost.

Comment: `I was hoping to get a Promise` and `chrome.tabs.executeScript already returns a promise` - so, you have a promise that you hoped for

Comment: @JaromandaX no, I have promisified the `executeScript` callback, which is fairly trivial. I want to execute async code and then `await` _that_ promise

Comment: Oh, I get it now, sorry for my confusion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that events and native objects are not directly available between the page and the extension. Essentially you get a serialised copy, something like you will if you do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`.

This means some native objects (for instance `new Error` or `new Promise`) will be emptied (become `{}`), events are lost and no implementation of promise can work across the boundary.

The solution is to use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to return the message in the script, and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` in popup.js to listen for it:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id, 
    { code: `(async function() { 
        // Do lots of things with await
        let result = true;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result, function (response) {
            console.log(response); // Logs 'true'
        });
    })()` }, 
    async emptyPromise => {

        // Create a promise that resolves when chrome.runtime.onMessage fires
        const message = new Promise(resolve => {
            const listener = request => {
                chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(listener);
                resolve(request);
            };
            chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listener);
        });

        const result = await message;
        console.log(result); // Logs true
    });
```

I've [extended this into a function `chrome.tabs.executeAsyncFunction`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync/blob/master/execute-async-function.js) (as part of [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync), which 'promisifies' the whole API):

```
function setupDetails(action, id) {
    // Wrap the async function in an await and a runtime.sendMessage with the result
    // This should always call runtime.sendMessage, even if an error is thrown
    const wrapAsyncSendMessage = action =>
        `(async function () {
    const result = { asyncFuncID: '${id}' };
    try {
        result.content = await (${action})();
    }
    catch(x) {
        // Make an explicit copy of the Error properties
        result.error = { 
            message: x.message, 
            arguments: x.arguments, 
            type: x.type, 
            name: x.name, 
            stack: x.stack 
        };
    }
    finally {
        // Always call sendMessage, as without it this might loop forever
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result);
    }
})()`;

    // Apply this wrapper to the code passed
    let execArgs = {};
    if (typeof action === 'function' || typeof action === 'string')
        // Passed a function or string, wrap it directly
        execArgs.code = wrapAsyncSendMessage(action);
    else if (action.code) {
        // Passed details object https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript
        execArgs = action;
        execArgs.code = wrapAsyncSendMessage(action.code);
    }
    else if (action.file)
        throw new Error(`Cannot execute ${action.file}. File based execute scripts are not supported.`);
    else
        throw new Error(`Cannot execute ${JSON.stringify(action)}, it must be a function, string, or have a code property.`);

    return execArgs;
}

function promisifyRuntimeMessage(id) {
    // We don't have a reject because the finally in the script wrapper should ensure this always gets called.
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const listener = request => {
            // Check that the message sent is intended for this listener
            if (request && request.asyncFuncID === id) {

                // Remove this listener
                chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(listener);
                resolve(request);
            }

            // Return false as we don't want to keep this channel open https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage
            return false;
        };

        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listener);
    });
}

chrome.tabs.executeAsyncFunction = async function (tab, action) {

    // Generate a random 4-char key to avoid clashes if called multiple times
    const id = Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);

    const details = setupDetails(action, id);
    const message = promisifyRuntimeMessage(id);

    // This will return a serialised promise, which will be broken
    await chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab, details);

    // Wait until we have the result message
    const { content, error } = await message;

    if (error)
        throw new Error(`Error thrown in execution script: ${error.message}.
Stack: ${error.stack}`)

    return content;
}
```

This `executeAsyncFunction` can then be called like this:

```
const result = await chrome.tabs.executeAsyncFunction(
    tab.id, 
    // Async function to execute in the page
    async function() { 
        // Do lots of things with await
        return true; 
    });
```

[This](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync/blob/master/execute-async-function.js) wraps the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`, and wraps the script in a `try`-`finally` before calling `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to resolve the promise.

Answer (score 5):

Passing promises from page to content script doesn't work, the solution is to use [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and to send only simple data between two worlds eg.:

```
function doSomethingOnPage(data) {
  fetch(data.url).then(...).then(result => chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result));
}

let data = JSON.stringify(someHash);
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: `(${doSomethingOnPage})(${data})` }, () => {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function listener(result) {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(listener);
      resolve(result);
    });
  }).then(result => {
    // we have received result here.
    // note: async/await are possible but not mandatory for this to work
    logger.error(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: Cheers, but I'm not sure what this answer adds that the already accepted one doesn't already have.

Comment: You are generally right @Keith, I just wanted to add a shorter answer with better parts that I could find in comments and other places – better page logic invoking, better listener handling, and to show that async/await are not mandatory to accomplish this task (it was not obvious for me when I read this for the first time).

Comment: `async` is never mandatory, you can always use promises and the Chrome APIs are callback-based (hence the link to the library in the accepted answer). If you're answer is better you need to explain that in the code - one thing is that the `async` hooks up exceptions passed by the linked library, without that you need to add your own checks on `chrome.runtime.lastError`.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is reading this but using the new manifest version 3 (MV3), note that this should now be supported.

`chrome.tabs.executeScript` has been replaced by `chrome.scripting.executeScript`, and [the docs explicitly state](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) that "If the [injected] script evaluates to a promise, the browser will wait for the promise to settle and return the resulting value."