# Wait for injected script execution to finish in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I have this function that runs when a certain button in my popup.html is clicked

popup.js

```js
async function execute () {
    console.log("Executing...")
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
    let res;
    try {
        res = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tab.id},
            files: ["/src/MainScript.js"],
        }, (a) => {
            console.log("Done callback?", a)
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return;
    }
    console.log("Result of script?", res)
}
```

`"Done callback?"` and `"Result of script?"` are printed inmediately after I run `execute()` so it's not waiting for it's execution to finish but to load the file, I think

I want to execute the `MainScript.js` file and wait for it's execution to finish. That file looks something like this:

MainScript.js

```js
(async function () {
   function Main () {
      this.run = async function () {
          // ...
      }
   }
   const main = new Main();
   await main.run();
})()
```

What I want to achieve is, when `MainScript.js` finishes it's execution I want to change some styling and elements in my popup.html.

I was wondering how to actually wait for the execution to finish or instead send a message from `MainScript.js` to my popup.js somehow or any alternative way, I'm opened to everything

**EDIT**

I tried the approach of messaging since I cannot wait for the execution to finish in manifest v3 (ty wOxxOm):

At the end of `MainScript.js` I placed this

```js
const main = new Main();
await main.run();

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(myExtensionId, {type: 'processDone', value: true});
```

And then in `background.js` I listen for that message

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("Hello background", request);
        // Set loading to false in localStorage...
    }
);
```

And the listener is never triggered BUT when I manually type the sendMessage through the console it works as expected, the service worker console prints `"Hello background"`

How can I send a message from the Content Script (`MainScript.js`) to the service worker `background.js`??

Just in case, this is my manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Extension name",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": "/images/favicon-32x32.png",
      "default_title": "Title"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation",
        "scripting",
        "storage"
    ],
    "externally_connectable": {
      "ids": [
        "*"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*.google.com/*"
      ]
    },
    "host_permissions": [
      "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: `executeScript` doesn't wait for the executed code neither in ManifestV2 nor in ManifestV3. This is how it works per the documentation and there's no other way currently. Maybe in the future it'll wait for a Promise, see https://crbug.com/1195807. Meanwhile you can adapt MV2 answer from [Using chrome.tabs.executeScript to execute an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43144485)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to adapt a solution in MV3 using messaging, could you please check it out?

Comment: The only thing to adapt was changing executeScript's call to MV3 semantics, but you went and changed onMessage listener too, which was a mistake, don't do it.