# Inject async function into page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome-extension, where I am trying to inject a function into the page. Injecting a regular function works without problems.

But as soon as I try to inject anything with async-functions, I get an error similar to this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined

For example, injecting an async-function directly.

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  func: async () => {
    console.log("Does it work?");
  }
});
```

Or even if I inject a regular function, but have an async function inside:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  func: () => {
    (async function () {
      console.log("Does it work?");
    })();
  }
});
```

It can't be right, that I am forced to write and inject synchronous code, making me unable to use the async/await functionality... Can it? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: ---------------

Upon further investigation, I can see that this function

```
async () => { console.log("Does it work?"); };
```

Get translated to this

```
function(){return e.apply(this,arguments)}
```

Which explains the `ReferenceError` but still leaves me clueless as to why this happens.

EDIT2: ---------------

So I tried to resort to "synchronous" code for now. But hoped I at least could use promises without async/await - But also no...

```
  chrome.storage.local.set({ someArray: [] })
    .then(() => console.log("It worked?"));
```

The code above results in the following error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

So no promises and no async/await for any injected code... Is this really the case?

Comment: Hi ! I'm far from being an expert of chrome extensions, but as it is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43179690/4698373), `async` `executeScript` should be replaced by `chrome.runtime` `Message` mechanism. Please have a look, I hope I'm wrong ^^

Comment: The API doesn't do such things. Judging by the `edit` part you're using a compiler/bundler/minifier so you need to configure it. For example, specify the minimal compilation target to Chrome 88 in your browserlist config or `ecma2020`, which will preserve `async` as is instead of recompiling it.

Comment: As for chrome.storage, it was promisified only in Chrome 95. Be aware that ManifestV3 is still half-implemented half-broken.

Comment: Maybe this is something for you https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill

Answer (score 3):

Injecting async function should not cause a problem. I have included a minimal example below to demonstrate.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
function inject(tab) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        func: async () => {
            window.alert("I'm here!");
        }
    })
}

// first open tab with some web page -> try inject there
chrome.tabs.query({
    url: "https://*/*"
}, function (tabs) {
    inject(tabs.shift())
});
```

Regarding OP and each edit:

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined` - identifier `g` does not exist: check what it is and where is it supposed to be defined
- EDIT 1: if using a compiler/bundler, renaming may be the source of a reference error
- EDIT 2:  `chrome.storage.local.set` [docs on usage indicate it needs a callback](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage) . There is no return value, i.e. it is undefined, cannot chain a `then` after it.